# Python Checking Multiple Lists For Similarities

Tags: python, list

For Example, i Have 3 lists

```
list1=['Oh','My','god','I','A','List!']

list2=['Oh','What','You','Dramatic?']

Keyword=['I','Dunno','What','You','Talking','About','DOT']
```

**EDIT**

I Want to compare keywords with list 1 and 2 separately. so it would become:

**EDIT**

```
common=['What','I','You']
```

What if i had more than 10 lists? <-- optional question.

Comment: `'I'` is not in `list2`, does it still belong in `common`?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't have to be in all 3 lists.

Comment: See my answer which should give you the result you are looking for (although possibly with a different ordering for `common`).

Comment: F.J, im testing it now. i'll probably be back in 5 minutes :)

Comment: Just edited my answer since you revised `common` to no longer include `'Oh'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your comment indicates that you want items that exist in both `Keyword` and ***either*** `list1` or `list2`, you probably don't want an intersection of all three.  Instead you should get the union of `list1` and `list2`, and then get the intersection of that result and `Keyword`.

Something like the following should give you what you want:

```
common = list((set(list1) | set(list2)) & set(Keyword))
```

Or an alternative approach that is more extensible (thanks to Karl for the shortened version):

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9, list10]
common = list(set().union(*lists).intersection(Keyword))
```

Comment: `set.union` accepts `*args`, so there is no reason to invoke `reduce`. It's also possible to feed lists to `union` and have them set-ified on demand, which may be a little faster and is certainly simpler. All you need is `common = list(set().union(*lists) & set(Keyword))`, or equivalently `common = list(set().union(*lists).intersection(Keyword))`

Answer (score 3):

Probably using a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```
common = list(set(list1) & set(list2) & set(Keyword))
```

However, you may need to define what you mean by "the words in common from each list", because the words you listed are only common to *two* of the lists you showed.

Comment: Well, I suspect you *do* want to use sets in any case. Try just `print list(set(list1) & set(list2))` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert them to sets then do an intersection:

```
intersect = list(set(list1) & set(list2)) & set(Keyword))
```